Fixed boundary conditions and Tau method for numerical PDE
I am trying to solve the diffusion équation $u_t - u_{xx} = 0$ on the domain $[0, 2\pi]$ with either periodic or fixed boundary conditions.
I absolutely want to work in the Fourier space, using the fft and the Galerkin-Fourier equations.
Under these assumptions, the diffusion équation is simply
$$ \partial_t\hat{u}_k = -k^2 \hat{u}_k $$
And the solution can quickly be implemented using the rfft:
N = 2**9
k = rfftfreq(N, 1/N)
u_hat_0 = rfft(u0)
def u_sol(t):
    return irfft(np.exp(-k**2 * t) * u_hat_0)

However, if I now want to fix the boundary condition (according to the initial one, ofc) I can apply the Tau method (because the Fourier basis does not satisfy this). In my naive implementation, I just adapt the last two coefficients at each timestep to satisfy the BC. However, I probably implemented it wrong and made the solution non-sense with a high-frequency term present everywhere even at high $t$ when I should have disappeared (due to the diffusion). Is this possible to do that in the fourier space?
